# Put a DIV over another with CSS only

Tags: css, html, position

I'm trying to put a div over another with just CSS because will have a PC and mobile style.

For example i have a container with 3 divs inside (style att just for this example):

```
<div>
<div style='float:left;'>div #1</div>
<div style='float:left;'>div #2</div>
<div style='float:right;'>div #3</div>
</div>
```

will show as

```
-----------------------
--div #1--div#2--div3--
-----------------------
```

but in mobile will show as

```
-----------------------
--div #1---------------
--div #2---------------
---------------div #3--
```

So i plan to use something different for mobile as:

```
-----------------------
--div #1-------div #3--
---------div #2--------
```

with resolutions from 320px to 1024px:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* HERE MY CSS */
}
```

So, Is this possible?. Thanks in advance for your help/suggestions.

Comment: Web standards are designed with the idea of a direct relation between the DOM element orders and the displayed result. What you want to do can be easier if you transform your DOM tree to put div #2 after div div #3. Can you use javascript?

Comment: Ok, if It's the only way then I'll use JS. How do i do this?

Comment: Is the reason that it's rendered like that on mobile maybe that the divs don't fit? Maybe you could get the same appearance as on desktop if you make the div sizes and size of contents relative (specifying size in % instead of px)

Comment: would putting div1 and div2 inside another div to manipulate their position their and put div 3 to the right of that parent div?

Comment: You can also transform DOM Tree on server side. You are not forced to use Javascript. But it's a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `div #3` between `div #1` and `div #2`, with your current css the result will be what you want.

```
<div>
    <div style='float:left;'>div #1</div>
    <div style='float:right;'>div #3</div>
    <div style='float:left;'>div #2</div>
</div>
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/b_m_h/ZaW4y/

Comment: Yep i figured out thanks. I'm ashamed for this question ^_^. Even if worked for my very own need, still important the comments about DOM and JS .